# Legend with the same width as the table without using threeparttable and minipage?

Tags: tables, width

I am creating tables but I would like the caption to be the same width as the table. I can't use the `threeparttable` and `minipage` environments because my university's standard template doesn't allow it. I need to use something within the `tabular` environment.

```
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo }
            \renewcommand\tabcolsep{3pt}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \hline
                    1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
                    2 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\
                    3 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\ \hline             
            \end{tabular}%
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

I don't want to specify the width manually because I have a lot of tables. I need some command as `\changecaptionwidth` or `\captionwidth` that uses the table width automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: your initial statement is very hard to understand. `minipage` is a standard latex environment, your university tempolate can't really stop you using that if it allows latex at all. Similarly you are asking for macros to measure the table width and make the caption match, that is exactly what `threeparttable` does. If for some weird reason you are not allowed to specify the package, then if you are allowed to use code from an answer here you are allowed to put the code of the threeparttable package in your preamble.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves -- duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322563/make-latex-table-caption-same-width-as-table

Comment: @jsbibra These are different questions. I look for a solution without using ```threeparttable``` or ```minipage```.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry. I will try to explain: I have to use a function called ```\larguratexto {caption width}``` within the ```tabular``` environment. This function is predefined in the university template and is used to specify the legend width, so that it stays in the standard.

Comment: You can do as I show in my answer measure the table and use `\wd\tblbox` but then if you re-set the table with the caption inside the table you will have to evaluate it twice rather than use `\usebox` which can have side effects. You would probably have been better to show yourr caption macro and ask that people modify that. I find it compleletely bizarre that any university would specify thesis requirements down to individual macro usage, but if yours does, I suppose you have to obey.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the command that is in the documentclass is ```\newcommand{\larguratexto}{\changecaptionwidth \captionwidth} ```, and in the main document I define ```\larguratexto{x}```, where ```x``` is the width of the table.

Comment: sorry that just tells me that `\larguratexto` is defined to be two commands `\changecaptionwidth` and ` \captionwidth` neither of which are defined by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the template default is that the caption is the size of the table. And I want a way to automate without having to manually measure and adjust the table. I am working on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am sure you are mistaken about the requirements, `minipage` is a core latex environment, if you are allowed to use latex, then you are allowed to use `minipage`. Similarly if you are allowed to use macros from an answer posted here, you are allowed to use the macros copied from `threeparttable` even if for some reason you are prevented from loading the file.

However it is simple enough to meet the requirements, just measure the table and set the caption to that width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\tblbox
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]% never use [h]
        \centering % not \begin{center} in floats 
            \renewcommand\tabcolsep{3pt}
            \sbox\tblbox{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \hline
                    1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
                    2 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\
                    3 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\ \hline             
            \end{tabular}}%
       % \end{center}
       \parbox{\wd\tblbox}{\centering
       \caption{Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo }
       \smallskip
       \usebox\tblbox
       }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo }
            \renewcommand\tabcolsep{3pt}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \hline
                    1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
                    2 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\
                    3 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\ \hline             
            \end{tabular}%
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, you are changing the caption width but only accidentally making it similar to the table width

Comment: @jsbibra Your answer is useful although I look for a solution without specifying the size for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne you are allowed to use `tabular`, I assume using a `tabularx` is not a problem either. You want to set any suitable total width for the `tabularx`, say `.8\textwidth` as I did below. Then, the caption is nothing other than a row in the tabularx. That row has only one cell like `p{\dimexpr.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}` to auto-wrap text inside.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{c*5{|X}}
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\dimexpr.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}{\caption{Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo}}\\[-.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
    2 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\
    3 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\ \hline             
  \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to load the `floatrow`  package, it defines a `\ttabbox` command, which by default sets the caption width to the table width (and similarly, it has an `ffigbox` command for figures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]%
        \centering %
        \ttabbox{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \hline
                    1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
                    2 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\
                    3 & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text & Text Text \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}%
       {\caption{Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo Exemplo }}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]